# A ligature for she/he

Tags: ligatures, kerning

**A Compulsory Edit** : I'm using this "s/he" thing quite a few times in the thesis. I've noticed that ⚧ (transgender unicode symbol) is even in the Unicode list, so I thought this might be a nice addition.

I'm not really losing sleep over it but it would have been nice if such a generic ligature was available maybe even for legal text. Probably in the end, I'll get tired and remove every single copy of it with a *he* and have a beer afterwards and write mean comments about vegetarian diet on Youtube.

Hence what I could have used in place for s/he is not important, take it as a pure typography challenge regardless of its use.

---

I find myself often grinding my teeth *I need to keep this gender neutral thing in mind...* even though I have no belief for its purpose. I can understand and respect the movement of increasing consciousness but over time, this showed only inconvenience rather than its original intended purpose. Maybe a genuine neutral pronoun is better but I don't know anything about linguistics so nevermind, I digress. ( for alternating use of `he`,`she`,`his` and `her` etc. automatically, look at Alan Munn's [`he-she`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/he-she) package).

I'm thinking of a standalone ligature for handling this once and for all in my document. Initially I've tried to make the slash a little more pleasing but due to the geometry of `s` and `h`, forward slash is blocked by the extender of `h` and backwards is sticking out.

**Question** : Can you please propose alternatives that would serve as a general ligature that can be applied to as many mainstream fonts as possible? I can cook up my own version for a specific font if the idea is generally applicable to any font. It would be really great if it works with PDFLaTeX but it's not a deal-breaker.

---

*Examples* : Font-specific tricks such as hiding `s` in the serif of `h`, .... (a failed attempt)

```
\raisebox{0.13bp}{s}\kern-2.1bphe
```

[image]

Letter-cropping-based ones : Well, I can't believe how ugly it turned out to be but for the sake of argument, here it is (butchered via TikZ):

[image]

Slash-based overwrites (also butchered via TikZ)

[image]

st and ct type ligatures, from wikipedia (I'd better not touch that)

[image: Wikipedia image]

and many more. Excuse my current lack of imagination but, it wouldn't do much good anyway if compared to our font experts here.

Comment: One way to be gender neutral would be to simply use "it". :-)  The PC police should love that.

Comment: You're going to need a ligature for “his/her”, too, aren't you :)

Comment: @cgnieder Ouch... right.

Comment: @PeterGrill I can keep everything `she` too and print on pink paper. A glam-rock thesis it should be.

Comment: One can also use the undetermined "one" in one's text. However one might feel that one's prose has become rather pompous.

Comment: I'd go with the word `shklee` [as seen in Futurama](http://theinfosphere.org/Yivo); `shklim` or `shkler` can be used as a replacement of "him" or "her". `:)`

Comment: I suggest printing `s` in `she` gray exactly 50% darkness, and using `hir` instead of `his/her`.

Comment: +1 for "it".  And the pink paper idea, too;).  (In fact, at one time I was toying with the idea of writing a math textbook addressed specifically to teenage girls:P.)

Comment: I quite like middle English "a". I've also used "ow", but not sure where that came from.

Comment: `they`? (I don't think a reader would recognise any of the typeset variations without effort)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In some sentences `they` becomes misleading let alone gender-neutral. A single user-multi user distinction becomes difficult for me to identify.

Comment: @tohecz Yes, that's the other option if this shape based distinction doesn't work out as I want. Graying out `s` is a nice idea too.

Comment: I personally like the TikZ abomination of `st` ligature... Gives kinda new meaning to 'baroque'! `:D` Btw: +1 for 'it'.

Comment: Great idea.  You might also want to ask this at http://www.typophile.com.  Someone among the hardcore type folks there may have already constructed such a ligature, and maybe there's already a free font that includes it.  In any event, the people there have a keen sense of type design, which seems like what the idea needs.  Some of the people there know LaTeX, too, so might have suggestions for LaTeX tricks to implement something.

Comment: @Mars Thank you. I'll post something whenever I have the chance.

Comment: @CountZero Sorry I meant the middle two. But I have those in TikZ too but I'm too ashamed to post those :)

Comment: What about just ignoring the political correctness and using the plain and simple masculine? How using correct grammar and plain structures negatively affects females is beyond my understanding and I consider the issue to be a politicised parade manufactured only to diverge people's attention from actually important subjects.

Comment: @HaroldCavendish Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: @percuße I like the letter-cropped one best, but I suspect this is just my devious side speaking, because it is obviously the ugliest one in terms of traditional typography (the only characteristic ugly fonts all have in common is randomly angled lines). As Harold says, why don't you just use the masculine, or put in a neutral word ("one", "they") once in a while? The feminisation of grammar is nonsensical; some people have even settled for "he or she", and haven't grown tired of it (or realised it made every one of their sentences insufferably ugly).

Comment: Why not use the female form everywhere if you're concerned about it? That's the simplest approach in my opinion.

Comment: @ienissei It has a weird Cosmopolitan look right? :)

Comment: Years ago in  "The Joy of TeX: A Gourmet Guide to Typesetting With the AMS-TeX Macro Package" Mike Spivak used gender neutral pronouns, hence did not need this ligature. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun

Comment: Please remove all references to gender:) It is oppressing grammar. The word "gender" has been reserved for grammatical categories.

Comment: The problem with this whole thing: its outcome might be cool with most hims and hers, but excludes all those who don't count themselves among either category. You're assuming and supporting a binary opposition that lacks empirical foundation.
An increasingly common typographic solution in German, which retains gender marking to an even larger degree than English, is the `_`: `s_he`, `steward_ess` etc, to account for the the entire spectrum of what's possible between ›him‹ and ›her‹. Or, wildcards: `s*he`, `steward*ess`. I don't endorse this, tho; I make use of the many means *language*
offers.

Comment: @NilsL Then you can't use *he or she* either. I really don't care about these political issues whether one feels like a sesquigender or not at all. I don't need empirical foundation. Language is not science it's all convention and it will change I'm only interested in the ligature. nothing else.

Comment: @HaroldCavendish, completely agree.

Comment: $e is close to my idea, but I want a capital S with a small / across the S

Comment: For handling the analogous problems (or “problems”) in French, see the typefaces at https://typotheque.genderfluid.space/index.html.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In [typophile.com](http://typophile.com/node/100528) forum, user `dudefellow` kindly posted the following nice idea which is kind of what I'm trying to get from my question. Hence, I'm posting it as a demonstration of what I'm after.

[image]

I would appreciate if we can limit the discussion to such propositions. It's more of a design question rather than the linguistic part as I've tried to clarify in the edit of my question.

More ideas about the ligature (thanks to dudefellow for the Armenian twist):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn’t this actually something, that belongs as edit into your question?

Comment: @Speravir It's not my answer hence the answer. And I think I need to steer this to the point that I wish to benefit from rather than alternatives of s/he usage.

Comment: *"dude follow"* me!!! :D

Answer (score 18):

Picking up a 500-year old idea...

[image]

Comment: Cool. But if you don't put the second in italics it becomes a bad `she`. That's why I made that integral-h in my post. The first one does read he or fhe anymore today, so i think we lost that front :)

Comment: my idea is that the right one is the italic version of the left one. So there's no non-italic version of the right one other than the left one. My reasoning behind all this: most people have forgotten that there used to be a second `s`: the `ſ`, so today we're able to put it to new use. People won't assign it a status as independent character. They won't say, »ah, thats a `she`«. That ligature (which can be found in a lot of typefaces; this is Minion) is distinctive enough to be perceived as something with its own meaning, but, with context, will still be interpreted as s+h. Or so I hope.

Comment: The reason I think this might be possible, in the long run, is that my language has a very similar glyph, `ß` (other languages, even Engliſh, *used to* have it as well). Hardly any native speaker of German today is aware that this is in fact a ligature composed of `ſ` and `s` (or `z`; scholars disagree). So what I'm relying on is the lack of a long-term typographic cultural memory :) ...but we should take that to typophile, I guess.

Comment: I only read she with long s. So it’s bad. But the idea could be used for long s kerned over n, what would be similar to one of the ideas posted by percusse.

Answer (score 5):

Why use ligatures? Ligatures are kind of anachronistic in this context. ;-) Use something modern: `color`!

```
\newcommand{\shehe}{%
\textcolor{gray}{s}he
}
```

Comment: Because it looks misprinted.

Comment: I know that I'm on the offside with that, especially in English, and that I might offend someone with it: It looks misprinted to me, every time I see any of these things: she/he, s/he, (s)he, these ligatures, my own solution. Can one not accept a preface sentence like "the use of any grammatical constructs such as pronouns is independent of any real gender or sex concerned"?

Comment: Yes but as you can see from the comments, everybody is avoiding the actual ligature answer. I already have tens of different linguistic alternatives other than the ligature itself, including your proposition too. I also have another long post here: http://typophile.com/node/100528 I appreciate yours too but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to stay strictly with a ligature solution. If introducing any kind of math notation, regardless of how bizarre it can be, is allowed so should the text.

Answer (score 5):

1) `$\mathrm \hbar$e`

[image: heshe]

(I would put a pure text --no math-- version if I knew how to)

2) `\~he`

[image: heshe2]

3) `\'he`

[image: heshe3]

4) `h\kern-1ex\c{}e`

[image: heshe4]

5) `{h\kern-1.5ex\c{}}\kern+0.5exe`

[image: heshe5]

6) `fie`

[image: fie2]

7) `\textit{fi}e`

[image: fie]

8) `$\int$\kern-0.9ex\textit{\i}e`

[image: intie]

I like the versions using accents because they are robust with respect to font change.
Also 6) and 7), which are actually real existing ligatures.

Some pure unicode options, for the fun of it, also much convenient to type:

```
%need xetex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
ħe ⴐe ƕe ჩe ɦe ḩe e ђe ɧe ҕe ꜧe Бe e he ԡe
\end{document}
```

[image: shelibertine]

**EDIT:** The results depends on the Font used. I didn't find a font that get all this right.

Comment: What font did you use in regard to the Unicode characters not appearing in the PDF? Libertine shows `ħ`, `ƕ`, `ɦ` and `ḩ`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, to be honest I think I don't know exactly how to choose the font in `xelatex`. I took some example from another answer and it didn't work. Anyway, I'll make this a wiki so anybody (?) can edit it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, ok, I finaly tried Libertine and found a couple of more characters.

Comment: `ɧ` also has the bonus of representing [a sound somewhat a mix between “sh” and “h”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal-velar_fricative).

Answer (score 4):

If you need a ligature, this would be my best answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
Then \raisebox{0.8ex}{\scriptsize s}\kern-0.2ex he would do something amazing.
\end{document}
```

[image: she/he ligature]

The only problem is the upper ligature of the s.

If it should look really good, you need a real ligature and consequently change the font for that. Try fontforge for that.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked the question. I need a real ligature. I know how to fiddle with fonts but the ligature is missing so it's not actually the answer to my question. That's why I've given the examples above with screenshots.

Comment: If you want to create the ligature by \kern and \raisebox and that stuff, you'll have to do it for every font and possibly every size each.

Comment: I'm looking for the ligature propositions I can handle the remaining difficulties. I also know TikZ too if I have to use it for this. But the question is about what to use not how to implement it. That's why I've included the edit.

Comment: The "s" better have the same size as the "h" does, or my feminist girlfriend will be furious if this becomes mainstream :-|

Answer (score 4):

I guess it’s impossible to create a ligature by only shifting and scaling the letters. A ligature is an own symbol/glyph which has to be designed individually as every other character too. There are two main reasons for that individual design process:

1. The *s* and the *h* must join each other and not only overlap
2. the stroke size of a smaller s must fit the regular strokes, which it
   doesn’t when scaling.

This image (taken from [Tosho’s code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101612/4918)) shows that 1. and 2. are not satisfied.

[image: s-he]

The only option would be to create the ligature with a font or vector editor, in the latter case the figure could be imported as an image or if the licence allows one can even add the new glyph to an existing font.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
s{\kern-0.172em}l{\kern-0.172em}\reflectbox{s}e 
\textsl{s{\kern-0.172em}l{\kern-0.09em}\reflectbox{s}{\kern-0.08em}e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it is just an approximation to illustrate an idea. 
This shape is almost symmetric, and as a bonus it even has a heart in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

I have a colleague who I thought might now, so I asked (s)him.  The answer was a simple "(s)he" (no ligature provided).